# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-2)$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> *Exercise:* Prove or disprove: $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3 − 2)$ is a field.

I would say, that it is not a field. We can use the following theorem:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $M$ an ideal in $R$. Then $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ if and only if $R/M$ is a field.

It seems that $\mathbb{Z}[x] \supsetneq (x, x^3 - 2) \supsetneq (x^3 - 2)$. That's because $(x, x^3 - 2)$ is the ideal of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ whose constant term is even, so it contains $x + 2$. But $x+2 \not\in (x^3 - 2)$.

Is that right?

And another question: $5$ doesn't seem to have an inverse in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3 − 2)$, too. So $(5, x^3 - 2)$ can't be maximal. But how does this ideal look like?

Thank you!

Comment: First part looks fine to me, and for the second part: indeed,  $\;x^3-2\in\Bbb F_5[x]\;$ is reducible, so the ideal $\;\langle 5\,,\,x^3-2\rangle\in\Bbb Z[x]\;$ cannot be maximal.